# Error:Cannot find control with path: 'users -> 0 -> data -> cat_name

Tags: angular, typescript

I tried to render the cat_name in textbox but i am not getting.
Below is my code to render the data

```js
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { 

this.myForm = this.fb.group({
users: this.fb.array([])
})

let dataArr = new FormArray([]);
dataArr.push(new FormGroup({
'cat_name': new FormControl(this.users[0].data[0].cat_name),
'category': new FormControl(this.users[0].data[0].category)
}));

let formArr = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.users;
formArr.push(fb.group({
firstname: this.users[0].firstname,
lastname: this.users[0].lastname,
street: this.users[0].street,
data: dataArr
}));
}
```

```html
<fieldset formGroupName="data">
cat_name:<input type="text" formControlName="cat_name">
</fieldset>
```

firstname and lastname render successfully in textbox but "data-sub array"  having the cat_name, i have tried to render but i am not getting below is my code url
[Code URL](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formgroup-selectbox-textarea-working-modify?file=app/app.component.ts)

I have attached the screen shot i am not able to render the cat_name field in textbox [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3Uvc.png)
And Below is my Full html code

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onMy(myForm.value)">  
<ng-container formArrayName="users">
<div *ngFor="let user of myForm.controls.users.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">

<select (change)="selectarch($event)">
<option>Select</option>
<option [value]="res.firstname" *ngFor="let res of users">{{res.firstname}}</option>
</select>   
<br><br>

First name:<input type="text" formControlName="firstname">
<br>
Last name:<input type="text" formControlName="lastname">
<br>
Last name:<input type="text" formControlName="street">
<br><br>

<select (change)="selectcolumn($event)">
<option>Select</option>
<option [value]="col.cat_name" *ngFor="let col of test[0].data">{{col.cat_name}}</option>
</select>    
<br><br>
<fieldset formGroupName="data">
cat_name:<input type="text" formControlName="cat_name">
</fieldset>

</div>
</ng-container>
<button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data is a formArray not formGroupName.you should iterate through the data formarray

```
  <fieldset formArrayName="data">
    <div *ngFor="let d of user.controls.data.controls; let ik=index" [formGroupName]="ik">
    cat_name:<input type="text" formControlName="cat_name">
    </div>
    </fieldset>
```

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formgroup-selectbox-textarea-working-modify-urwpgs?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: it's working, but dynamic render not working, i have tried with the below code please help me ---selectarch(cat){

this.test=this.users.filter(data =>data.firstname === cat.target.value);

let arr = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.users;

arr.controls[0].patchValue({firstname:this.test[0].firstname,lastname:this.test[0].lastname,street:this.test[0].street});

let arr2 = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.users[0].data;
arr2.controls[0].patchValue({cat_name:this.test[0].data[0].cat_name});

}

Comment: when i am selecting the selectbox i got formarray and with in that i render first name but i am not rendering the cat_name

Comment: Below is the url : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formgroup-selectbox-textarea-working-modify-1kxvyn?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

ReactiveForm is very rewarding, but very hard to begin with, an alternative option that may be easier to implement is Template-Driven-Form Approach.

That said, the issue you're experincing here, is that you're trying to access a second formArray, within a formArray, without declaring so.

you've declared `formArrayName="users"`, and iterated through it with `let user of myForm.controls.users.controls`, (note, this is equivalent to `let userCtrl of myForm.get('users').controls`) but you also need to iterated through users' data.controls

You need to declare a formArrayName for each level of FormArray

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

<div formArrayName="users">
  <div *ngFor="let userCtrl of myForm.get('users').controls; let j = index;"
       [formGroupName]="j" >
    <div formArrayName="data">
      <fieldset *ngFor="let dataCtrl of userCtrl.get('data').controls; let i = index;"
                [formGroupName]="i">
        cat_name:<input type="text"  formControlName="cat_name">
      </fieldset>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</form>
```